# Looking for allocation of JVM heap

Tags: jvm, strace

I've run the straced JVM (OpendJDK 11):

`strace -e trace=mmap java -Xms8192m Main`

The output is:

```
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7effda5fa000
mmap(NULL, 2158880, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7effda1c3000
mmap(0x7effda3d1000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xe000) = 0x7effda3d1000
mmap(NULL, 246024, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7effda5bd000
mmap(NULL, 4131552, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7effd9dd2000
mmap(0x7effda1b9000, 24576, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1e7000) = 0x7effda1b9000
mmap(0x7effda1bf000, 15072, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7effda1bf000
mmap(NULL, 2212016, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7effd9bb5000
mmap(0x7effd9dd0000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1b000) = 0x7effd9dd0000
mmap(NULL, 2109712, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7effd99b1000
mmap(0x7effd9bb3000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x2000) = 0x7effd9bb3000
mmap(NULL, 2221184, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7effd9792000
mmap(0x7effd99ab000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x19000) = 0x7effd99ab000
mmap(0x7effd99ad000, 13440, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7effd99ad000
mmap(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7effda5bb000
mmap(NULL, 21206808, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7effd8358000
mmap(0x7effd963f000, 1032192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x10e7000) = 0x7effd963f000
mmap(0x7effd973b000, 354072, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7effd973b000
mmap(NULL, 246024, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0x7effda5bd000
mmap(NULL, 3702848, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7effd7fcf000
mmap(0x7effd8348000, 49152, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x179000) = 0x7effd8348000
mmap(0x7effd8354000, 12352, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0x7effd8354000
mmap(NULL, 3789144, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7effd7c31000
mmap(0x7effd7fcd000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x19c000) = 0x7effd7fcd000
mmap(NULL, 2192432, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0x7effd7a19000
mmap(0x7effd7c2f000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x16000) = 0x7effd7c2f000
mmap(NULL, 1052672, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK, -1, 0) = 0x7effda4ba000
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

I set the initial size of the heap to 8192M and I tried to find allocation of the heap in the output of the strace. I could not find it. Why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add `-f` option (Trace child processes).

Running Java code in a primordial thread used to cause many problems, see [JDK-6316197](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6316197) for details.

`java` launcher creates a JVM in a new thread.

Comment: Thanks, it helped. @apangin, do you know where I can read about internal representation (management) of the heap by JVM?

Comment: @Gilgamesz That's too broad question. I can only give a similarly broad answer - on the internet.

Comment: ok, I don't mean the garbage collection (and young / tenured generation, metaspace, and so on). I mean how does JVM keep a heap (for example, as a free list). I would like to understand it. This is what is interesting for me. Anyway, thanks for your time :)

Comment: @Gilgamesz Look for [collectedHeap](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/hotspot/share/gc/shared/collectedHeap.hpp) in HotSpot sources. Each GC has its own implementation of collectedHeap though.